# How to create this paypal button?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I would like to create a paypal button that has this checkout page:

[image]

Instead, my checkout page is this:
[image]

Why ?

The source code is the same but the checkout page is different, why ?

This is the code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxx">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/it_IT/IT/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/it_IT/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first screenshot is the checkout flow for PayPal BuyNow, Add to Cart buttons.
The second screenshot is the checkout flow PayPal Subscription button.